# Can I keep the effect of the Algid Enhancment spell if the Mantle of the Icy Soul spell ends?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, cleric, duration

The description of the Algid Enhancement spell (*Frostburn*, p. 88) says

> You energize cold creatures with a surge of coldfire. **Creatures with
> the cold subtype affected** by this spell gain a +1 deflection bonus to
> AC, +1d8 temporary hit points, a +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls,
> and a +2 bonus on saving throws against fire effects. Each of these
> enhancements increases by +1 for every three caster levels. So a
> 12th-level caster grants a +5 deflection bonus to AC, an extra 1d8+4
> temporary hit points, a +5 enhancement bonus on attack rolls, and a +6
> resistance bonus on saving throws against fire effects.
>
> This spell has no effect on creatures not of the cold subtype.
>
> *Coldfire Component:* One ounce of coldfire.

I can earn this subtype with Mantle of the Icy Soul (*Frostburn*, p. 101) for 1 hour/level.

What happens if Mantle of the Icy Soul ends before Algid Enhancement? Can I keep the upgrades, even if I don't have the cold subtype anymore?

Answer (score 6):

This question effectively comes down to whether or not D&D 3.5e utilizes “constant targeting”—that is, if a creature is the valid target of a spell, and at some point after it has come into effect, that creature ceases to be a valid target of the spell, does the spell effect end?

We have a few questions on that subject:

- [What happens if a druid uses Share Spells to share a spell that blocks extraordinary abilities with their companion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142271/4563)
- [Can one wild shape to escape from the Hold Person spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152598/4563)

The answers to both of those questions note the lack of any real, official answer to this question, and quote from the FAQ:

> > **If, while under the effect of a spell that depends on type (such as *hold person*), my character is transformed into a different creature type by *polymorph*, does the spell’s effect remain?**
>
> *Yes. A spell only checks to see if you are a legal target when it is cast. If you become an illegal target later (such as via the* polymorph *spell), the spell remains in effect.* (87)

Both also note [the problems with the D&D 3.5e FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/4563).

Unfortunately, while it’s the best we’ve got for this, it isn’t solid enough that you can avoid asking your DM about it. Ultimately, only your DM can answer this.

Note, however, that *algid enhancement* has another consideration here: the qualification isn’t a part of the **Target** of the spell, it’s a part of the effect. One could argue that, no, D&D 3.5e does not have constant targeting (or at least our game doesn’t), but this still does not work because the effect of *algid enhancement* is the thing that checks for the cold subtype, and that does update constantly. You can also argue that this works the same as targeting, and that it works constantly or not.

In short, any one of these four answers is a plausible interpretation of the rules:

- D&D 3.5e has constant targeting, so spells “fall off” if their target ceases to be a valid target,

  - and *algid enhancement*’s effect works the same way, or
  - but *algid enhancement*’s effect does not have constant updates, so if you had the cold subtype when it was cast on you, you keep its benefit for the duration,

  or
- D&D 3.5e does not have constant targeting, so spells continue for their entire duration so long as the target was valid at the time of casting, even if they cease to be afterwards,

  - and so *algid enhancement* likewise is maintained in whatever state it was first applied in, or
  - but *algid enhancement*’s effect does constantly update, and so you only get the benefit while you have the cold subtype; if you lose it, you will have to cast *mantle of the icy soul* or otherwise regain the cold subtype in order to benefit.

So yeah, this can go any way. Ask your DM.

Answer (score 2):

This question gets at the idea of "constant targeting" versus "one-time targeting" — that is, whether a spell:

- ...checks the properties of its target once when cast, and then continues to have the appropriate effect for its duration, even if the target changes in some relevant way

OR

- ...checks the properties of its target continuously for the duration of the spell, updating the effects of the spell dynamically as the target changes

This question often comes up in [discussions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142274/30299) of whether spells that only work on targets with a specific creature type (like [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/enlargePerson.htm)) are suppressed if their target changes its type (like via [Polymorph](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorph.htm)), or continue to work as long as the target was valid when the spell was cast.

Unfortunately, there's no definitive answer to this question in the rules.  The closest thing I'm aware of is an entry in the [D&D 3.5 FAQ](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a), which says:

> **If, while under the effect of a spell that depends on type (such as hold person), my character is transformed into a different creature type by polymorph, does the spell’s effect remain?**
>
> *Yes. A spell only checks to see if you are a legal target when it is cast. If you become an illegal target later (such as via the polymorph spell), the spell remains in effect.*

This implies that you would continue to benefit from Algid Enhancement as long as you had the [cold] subtype *when the spell was cast*, regardless of what happened after that.  However, this is only as trustworthy as the FAQ, which is [not very](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq).  Beyond that, the only answer is "ask your DM."